# Data storing in firebase database is not happening in real device in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the phone authentication for user login, at the login screen I have two fields, i.e Name, and Phone number, I want to store these phone number and name in the firebase real-time database using the same UID, I can create a database under the same UID but Name and Phone number values are not stored in the database, this is not happening in the real device but in Emulator everything works fine

```dart
try {
await FirebaseAuth.instance

.signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthProvider. credential(

verificationId: verificationCode, smsCode: pin))

.then((value) async {
if (value.user !- null) {

Map userDataMap = {
"name": widget.driverName,
"phone": widget .phoneNumber,
};
//print(userDataMap):
//code correction variable

await driverRef.child(value.user.uid).set(userDataMap):

currentFirrebaseuser - value.user,
Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Successful"):

Navigator.pushAndRemoveuntil(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (context) -» MainDriverScreen()), //MaterialPageRoute
(route) -» false),
}
});
} catch (e) £
FocusScope.of( context).unfocus( ):
scaffoldkev currentState
```

Comment: Do you get any errors when you try to store the values on the database?

Comment: No, I am not getting any erros

Comment: Did you find a solution? i am having the same issue

Comment: Has anyone found a solution, I also have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added to your AndroidManifest.xml

Path:

> project\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

above `<application/>` for internet permission on the real device.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason if you're using the same wifi with the emulator it doesn't work, you have to switch your device to a mobile network. after a lot of trying and searching this worked for me.